# Python / SQLAlchemy: How to delete records IN allocation tables?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, associations

below I have brought you an executable program. There are comments in this program to make the situation easier to understand. Please read the comments. Well What I want? I want the porgram to delete/remove only record(s) in an allocation table (*Allocation_Film_Genre*) - not rows in the tables like *Film* or *Genre*. As you can see, in the example I assigned the movie "Saw" to the genre "Comedy". A (deliberate) mistake. Now I want to resolve this constellation, but I don't want to delete "comedy" and "Saw" from the database, but only the assignment. But how?

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, backref

sqlite_url = 'sqlite:///test.sqlite'

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(sqlite_url, echo = True)

Base = declarative_base()


class Allocation_Film_Genre(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'allocation_film_genre'
  genre_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('genre.id'), primary_key=True)
  film_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('film.id'), primary_key=True)

  genre = relationship("Genre", backref=backref("allocation_film_genre", lazy='dynamic', cascade="all, delete-orphan" ))
  film = relationship("Film", backref=backref("allocation_film_genre", lazy='dynamic', cascade="all, delete-orphan" ))

class Film(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'film'
  id = Column(Integer,  primary_key=True, unique=True)
  name = Column(String(80))

class Genre(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'genre'
  id = Column(Integer,  primary_key=True, unique=True)
  name = Column(String(80))

# Let us create all tables with certain columns
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Now we have to create a session to work with.
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# We want to save some movies
film1 = Film(name="Saw")
film2 = Film(name="Amageddon")
film3 = Film(name="Little Stuart")
film4 = Film(name="Doom Day")

session.add_all([film1, film2, film3, film4])
session.commit()

# By the way we also want to save some genres 
genre1 = Genre( name = "Horror")
genre2 = Genre( name = "Comedy")
genre3 = Genre( name = "Psycho")
genre4 = Genre( name = "Thriller")

session.add_all([genre1, genre2, genre3, genre4])
session.commit()

# Hold on, we know we created an allocation table, because
# one movie can contains one or more genre, otherwise, one genre
# also can contains one or more movie, right? Let take us a look.
# For simulate we use the movie named 'Saw".
film_obj1 = session.query(Film).filter(Film.name=="Saw").one()
genre_obj1 = session.query(Genre).filter(Genre.name=="Horror").one()

film_obj2 = session.query(Film).filter(Film.name=="Saw").one()
genre_obj2 = session.query(Genre).filter(Genre.name=="Psycho").one()

film_obj3 = session.query(Film).filter(Film.name=="Saw").one()
genre_obj3 = session.query(Genre).filter(Genre.name=="Comedy").one()

allocation1 = Allocation_Film_Genre(film=film_obj1, genre=genre_obj1)
allocation2 = Allocation_Film_Genre(film=film_obj2, genre=genre_obj2)
allocation3 = Allocation_Film_Genre(film=film_obj3, genre=genre_obj3)

session.add_all([allocation1, allocation2, allocation3])
session.commit()

# Ok, we are done. Alle movies and genre are saved, and we also saved all
# allocation records. But wait! There is a mistake. Saw isn't a comedy. Damn!
# Shame on me!

# And now, I don't know what I have to do.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sqlalchemy import and_

allocation_obj_to_delete _list=session.query(Allocation_Film_Genre).join(Film).join(Genre).filter(and_(Film.name=='Saw',Genre.name=="Comedy")).all()

for obj in allocation_obj_to_delete:
    session.delete(obj)
session.commit()
```

Joined query and delete the objects

Comment: I think there is a mistake. Your example code deletes **all** records from allocation table, which assigned to the film named "Saw", right? But I only want the program to delete the mistake allocation between Saw and Comedy. All the other genre are corect. We know that Saw is a thriller and also a horror film :)

Comment: Oops missed one condition. Updated the answer.

Comment: Your code doesn't work. If i run it, nothing happens - no traceback. After run, I took a look in the created database and the constellation is also there. It wasn't deleted.

Comment: You need to commit the session

Comment: which session did you mean?

Comment: Engine bounded session which you are using the query the db. Updated the answer

Comment: Great, its work like a charm. Well, when I take a look at your query, its looks very ugly, like a hack and its also long. Is that normal?

Comment: Short question. You used the method `all()`,  but I thin' I can just use òne()`,  right? Because the constellation Saw and Comedy is unique in an allocation table, right?

Comment: Yeah, you can use one() it will just return one row. All will fetch all the rows satisfying the criteria. I wish I could shorten the code but I can't in the particular use case. It is similar to SQL but in fancy form :P

Comment: You mean, in SQL language it will be look more ugly? :)

Comment: In your code example you use the and_()-function. But I tried to use the query without it, and its work! Here: `allocation_obj_to_delete = session.query(Allocation_Film_Genre).join(Film).join(Genre).filter(Film.name=="Saw",Genre.name=="Comedy").one()` . Quesion: What is the difference?

Comment: It is the same. It is just I use every time just to be on the safe side because many times while dealing with subqueries it becomes messy. By default, it will generate `and` similar to SQL. It is okay to ignore that in this case.